# Angular 7 interceptor get local storage value and add to header

Tags: angular, angular7

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

try {
      const token: any = localStorage.getItem('ibAccessToken');
      console.log('token string', token);

      if (token) {
        console.log('token if',  token)
          request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +  token) });
      }

      if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
          request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
      }

      request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });

      return next.handle(request).pipe(
          map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
              if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                  console.log('event--->>>', event);
              }
              return event;
          }));
}catch(ex){
  return ;
} }
```

Local storage value display only null. because interceptor called the very first time. please help me, how can I achieve this code?

Comment: Where are you setting the ibAccessToken to localstorage? That is important. If your code sets it after this, then it will be null alone.

Comment: I have set ibAccessToken to local storage on login success. after this only I need to add request header to every request. in that time how to achieve this.

Comment: i have tried auth service for getting localstorage that is also not working

Comment: I suspect the localstorage.setItem only. Please confirm what you are setting there. If it is null there, then you wont achieve this anywhere.

Comment: I have to get the storage value in the console. and I have tried to pass in header request it shows only [object object]

Comment: That is the reason. It should not be object array. The localstorage value should be set as string. Try to convert object array to string and store it.

Comment: localStorage.setItem("ibAccessToken", JSON.stringify(<your object here>));

Comment: Mohamed, have you tried it? Any luchh

Comment: I have tried it but it not working can you write code for me.

Comment: Can you post your localstorage.setItem line

Comment: this.localStorage.setItem("ibAccessToken", JSON.stringify(data.access_token)).subscribe(() => {});

Comment: You had subscribed to data.access_token and you didnt store it anywhere. Please try with the below code on my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
(data.access_token).subscribe((response) => {
    // If you subscribe to access_token from some where do this
    const accessToken = response;
     // If your accessToken is not a string and if it object, do stringify other wise add the access token directly to localstorage.
     this.localStorage.setItem("ibAccessToken", JSON.stringify(accessToken));
})
```